# How to use Ajax with Flask

Tags: jquery, python, ajax

I'm visualizing live charts like the example here: [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data). Basically, its an Ajax request for data from a PHP script `live-server-data.php` that generates  random data :

```
/**
 * Request data from the server, add it to the graph and set a timeout 
 * to request again
 */
function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/',
        success: function(point) {
            var series = chart.series[0],
                shift = series.data.length > 20; // shift if the series is 
                                                 // longer than 20

            // add the point
            chart.series[0].addPoint(point, true, shift);

            // call it again after one second
            setTimeout(requestData, 1000);    
        },
        cache: false
    });
}


//---live-server-data.php
<?php 
$x = time() * 1000;  
$y = rand(0, 100);   
$ret = array($x, $y);
echo json_encode($ret);
?>
```

How to do a similar thing in Flask i.e. request randomly generated numbers from Flask?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import random, datetime, json
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():

    x = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
    y = random.randint(0, 100)
    return json.dumps([x, y])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its much simpler in Flask:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    x = datetime.timestamp(datetime.now()) * 1000
    y = random.randint(0, 100)
    return json.dumps([x, y])
```

But note that you'll have to add the following imports at the top in order for this to work:

```
import random, datetime, json
from datetime import datetime
```

Comment: Thanks. How to call the data from Ajax request? I put the code in Flask but am getting the raw values on index.html. How to pass the data to Highcharts like in the example?

Comment: Don't use `app.py`, replace it with your actual URL endpoint. For example, it will the `http://localhost/` or just `/` if its the same index page.

Comment: And try that endpoint without ajax, by just opening that url in normal browser first.

Comment: Yes it will. The `index()` function will trigger when you open the home page ("/"). See the `@app.route("/")` attribute definition above it.

Comment: Flask works differently than php. The user isn't given access to the entire root folder, but to only those routes that you explicitly define in your app code.

Comment: Oh I see! so how to now pass the values to the chart? I can see the ajax function is called again after a certain time to refresh the chart: `setTimeout(requestData, 1000)`

Comment: Call it to the root url ("/") like you already are in the code. Didn't that work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154082/discussion-between-dougkruger-and-prahlad-yeri).